# Traefik Docker Swarm Mode multiple networks listen address

Tags: docker, traefik, docker-swarm-mode

I can't figure out how to implement this, if it's even possible:

[image]

I want to allow Traefik container to expose ports only on Traefik Network.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

To clarify, my question isn't technical and not about docker but about Traefik. Since Traefik supports docker (a dynamic environment), is it capable of exposing ports only for one docker network with dynamic ip address it receives. If it does then please explain how to achieve it (which comes to one configuration line or one parameter to add in container deployment). If it doesn't then it's a nice toy for development and not enterprise ready since it can't handle security in dynamic environments.

Comment: Do you have a stack (compose) file you're working on? What have you tried that's not working?

Comment: I don't have a compose file, just working via terminal. I want Traefik to listen on **specific interface / dynamic IP** assigned by docker.

Comment: So you're wanting someone to give you all service create commands and a traefik config for that? Maybe to get better help with this, why not update the question with examples of commands and configs you've tried and we can suggest fixes rather than designing the whole solution for you.

Comment: Hey Bret, thank you for your reply. My question isn't technical and focuses on Traefik as a product. I've updated my question. There is no need to add any technical instruction on how to create or deploy  networks or containers but only the specific config param on deployment/configuration of the Traefik product.